# MS SQL Server 2014 - Deadlock error when creating a user-defined table type and use it in the same transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, deadlock, user-defined-types, table-valued-parameters

For testing purposes, I am creating a user-defined table type and then use it to pass some testing data in a table-valued parameter to a query. However, if I do so in the same transaction, I always get a deadlock error. Unfortunately, I need to do them in the same transaction so that I can rollback the tests' side-effects.

Any suggestions or work-arounds?

Comment: If it's all happening in one transaction, why not just a table variable? What's the UDTT adding here?

Comment: You're deadlocking on a table you're creating? Is this a parallelism deadlock? Because, I'm trying to envision any other cause for a deadlock that involves a single transaction, a single thread, and no external processes and I can't.

Comment: I believe I've seen this issue several times historically on MS Connect but can't find it now (since it's retired), and that it was closed as both 'wont fix' and 'by design' - but I don't remember the details.

Comment: See this blog post https://sqlperformance.com/2013/11/t-sql-queries/single-tx-deadlock

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I do not know how to pass my IEnumerale as a table variable to my query using Dapper.

Comment: There is no workaround except don't do that in the same transaction. The system transaction that creates the instance of the table in `tempdb` is incompatible with the user transaction. So you need separate code to create it outside your tran and add explicit code to drop it rather than just relying on rollback to sort it out

Comment: @GrantFritchey It is one thread and Cedersved is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will work if you create the user defined table type outside of the transaction. Based on your question, I guess this could be an option as the creation of a new user defined table type is unlikely to cause any side-effects - or am I missing something?

1. Create user defined table type
2. Begin tran
3. Rollback tran
4. Drop user defined table type

Comment: Hi Cedersved. The UDTT is only temporary for the testing and I want to roll it back when done.